# python-pptx - "item is not an embedded ole object or microsoft chart"

Tags: python-pptx

I use python-pptx to generate a set of charts.

When I try to link these charts to a 3rd party data analysis tool, using the tool's addin, I get this error:

"the selected item is not an embedded ole object or microsoft chart"

I don't get this error if I insert the chart manually in pptx and then connect it to 3rd path data analysis tool.

[image]

I thought python-pptx generates native powerpoint objects?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, weird. I suspect the answer lies in how the third-party tool accesses the charts. If you have access to that code that's probably the right next-step direction.

If (as I suspect) it is a closed-source tool, you'd have to rely on the vendor to do the diagnosis. The charts open up and behave correctly in PowerPoint, right? And I can tell you they've been doing that for a long time, and in LibreOffice and other clients as well, so I expect it's some small detail of how they access charts, possibly using a Microsoft C# library or something.

Anyway, those are the wages of closed-source so they'll be the ones to get you to the next step. If they can pinpoint the gap, like perhaps a certain element not present in the XML then we could look at how we might accommodate that in `python-pptx`.

You might get farther if you don't lead with "I generated this chart with `python-pptx` and it doesn't work with your tool." Better perhaps to say "Here's this legitimate PPTX file that opens fine in PowerPoint and doesn't work with your tool." No sense in focusing their mind on an easy "out" from the start.

One small possible difference that occurs to me is whether the chart is directly placed or whether it is inserted into a chart placeholder. The differences are extremely minor in the XML, but might be worth a try if that rings a bell.

Comment: Yup, the charts open and behavour correctly in powerpoint. I've passed on a sample pptx to the 3rd party for them to examine. I'mm sure it's something on their side. Will let you know what they say. Thanks for your help Steve.